# how to get jquery data from a dynamic web project Eclipse into mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, eclipse

I am currently working in a dynamic web Project in Eclipse, that works with JSPs, CSS and Javascript files.

I was able to connect my MySQL database to my project via JDBC driver. I can add and read the data from my database with java code.

For my Login Page everything works fine, since I could use a "form".

But now I need to save jquery data to the database. The user is able to dynamically drop resizable, draggable and CSS-defined shapes on a canvas. The position and size of these shapes is saved in jquery data:

```
    var dropped = $(ui.draggable).clone().addClass(
                'set').attr('id', count++)
                .appendTo(this)
                .data({
                    'posleft' : ui.position.left,
                    'postop' : ui.position.top,
                    'width' : ui.draggable[0].offsetWidth,
                    'height' : ui.draggable[0].offsetHeight
                });
```

My question is: How do I get the jquery data into my mysql database?

I read that there a several options, but I was not able to figure out, if and how it is possible to combine those with my dynamic web project.

E.g. if using php, how would I add php code to my project? Can I add some php files to my dynamic web project in Eclipse? Or do I need to create a new PHP Project? If yes, can I run my javascript/jquery code in that php project?

Or is there an easier way to get the jquery data into a mysql database?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ajax` to resolve this issue :

```
$.ajax({
url: "test.php" 
data : {
   // put your data here. eg. 
    data1 : data1
 }
 }).done(function() {
   //Do something
 });
```

More informations [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my questions is still: How can I run this php file in my dynamic web project? I have php installed and it works, when I run it via terminal, but in my dynamic web project it does not work. Is it even possible to run php files in a dynamic web project t (with Tomcat)? When I navigate to http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/phpTest.php it shows me the php code as plain text

Comment: You should install a web server locally such Wampserver for Windows, Lamp for Lunix or Xampp for Mac. Put your project under the 'www' repository , then you will call your page like this : http://localhost/phptest.php. You can also install apache2 server and run the project directly from eclipse